# How to automate drag and drop and click in Canvas Element using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: canvas, selenium-webdriver

I have to create automated tests for automating click and drag and drop in Html canvas.

Comment: have you tried using action chains?

Comment: How can i use action chains for drag and drop as i am having both source and target element as same canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions) about **Advanced User Actions** might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Well long story short we can do this using Actions class. Below code should get you started.

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.dragAndDrop(fromLocation, toLocation).perform();
```

Just ensure both fromLocation and toLocation are webelements. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
  Actions act=new Actions(driver);
  act.DragAndDrop(webElement_Source, webElement_Target)).Build().Perform();
```